# How to fix context menu in Solution Explorer in VS 2022

Tags: visual-studio, contextmenu

After installing some extensions for SSIS and SSRS, the refresh option is showing up 4 times in the context menu.  How do I remove them?  This only shows up when right clicking a file.
[image]

Looked for appropriate settings in Tools/Customize/Commands/Context menu/.  But couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a true solution to this as requested, although I did spend probably an hour-and-a-half yesterday staring at my screen as I scrolled through every context menu in the `Customize` dialog looking for `Refresh` items. I didn't realize before I'd started how many there were, or I probably wouldn't have set out on that task, but once I was invested I didn't want to stop. Needless to say, I had the same outcome as @thomas-johnson.

As I said, I didn't find a solution but I did find a workaround, at least for me. I don't use both extensions all of the time, and disabling just one of them removes three of the context menu items.

```
Microsoft Analysis Services Projects
  Refresh items when enabled: 4
  Refresh items when disabled: 1

SQL Server Integration Services Projects 2022
  Refresh items when enabled: 4
  Refresh items when disabled: 1
```

All I have to do is disable the one extension that I'm not using for that month or three, and three `Refresh` context menu items go away with it.

That remaining context menu item is the only one that I could customize away. It's under `Project and Solution Context Menus | Project` and it's the `Refresh` item about 20 items down. I removed it just to get one more item off of that massive context menu, since there's a `Refresh` button on the Solution Explorer toolbar.

.....

Right after posting this, I went searching for a beta version of either extension which could have a fix. I didn't find one, but I did find out that they know about the issue.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects2022

Known Issues:-

1. In the context menu (right mouse button) on objects in the project (e.g. the solution, a package) in Visual Studio, many of the entries appear many times. This happens only when Microsoft Analysis Services Projects 2022 is installed together.

Answer (score 0):

You could try closing all instances of Visual Studio and then from the developer command prompt run

```
devenv /Setup
```

That will sometimes fix issues from extensions.

See the docs for devenv.exe (Visual Studio) command line switches at "[Devenv command-line switches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2022)" and "[Devenv command-line switches for VSPackage development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/devenv-command-line-switches-for-vspackage-development?view=vs-2022)".

A different step to try is to run the Visual Studio Installer and run a 'Repair'.

Comment: Thanks for the response but neither option fixed it.
FYI: Running Repair will "wipe" any personalization's/settings you have setup in VS.